# php require_once path difference between windows and linux

Tags: php, windows, linux, relative-path, require-once

I have a file located in my CakePHP root folder placed under a folder named cron. Path is:

```
c:/wamp/www/project/cron/daily.php
```

This file requires another file placed inside vendor folder of cake structure, like this:

```
require("/../vendors/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
```

And i run this **daily.php** from task scheduler. This is the scenario in my development site.(Windows system). It works fine as expected. When i migrated the project to Ubuntu(production site), the **require** statement started causing issues; it cant find the required file. I made a small change there, like this:

```
require("../vendors/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php"); <= removed the preceding slash
```

And it worked. So my doubt is, is there a difference in how parent directory notation work in widows and Linux? If so, how can i overcome this? Its not feasible to remove a slash every time I move the project from my development site(windows) to production site (Linux).

---

I tried this:

```
 require("./../vendors/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
```

It worked in linux. But gave "no such file directory" error in windows. It seems windows works only with:

```
 require("/../vendors/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
```

---

**Solution**

From @TWCrap's help problem was solved as follows:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__)."/../vendors/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
```

It works in both windows and linux(* tears of joy *). But in windows it produces path as:

```
C:\wamp\www\project\cron/../vendors/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php
```

This path looks ugly and i hope it wont cause probs in future!

-Thanks guys!

Comment: the / in the begining in linux meens to Root directory (as if you wrote C:/ in windows). anyway I don't think you need the / in the begining for windows too. no ?!

Comment: Use an an absolute path?

Comment: FYI, `/..` is a nonsensical root path on any sane OS. What you are saying is "directory above the root directory", which obviously does not exist. This will effectively be treated as the root. I suspect that what you meant is `./..` which is, incidentally, the most efficient way to specify a path for `include`/`require` because it will prevent PHP from searching through the `include_path` and look directly at the exact location you specified.

Comment: @Yazmat it should work without / at the beginning in windows. (../) refers to parent dir in windows. But somehow here it behaves weird.

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__) == __DIR__`. Or am I wrong.

Comment: @Oussama - In this context, '/' does not mean root directory.  It is used to go back to a subdirectory.  So the context is very important.

Comment: @DaveRandom - In this context, '/' is not used as a root directory.  Please read a note I sent to Oussama.  Context is very important.

Comment: @Yazmat - You must have it.  '/' is used as a closure of current directory.  In this context, '/'  is not used as a root directory.

Comment: @DerpyNerd - They mean the same.

Comment: I am surprised that require("./../vendors/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php"); didn't work for Windows.  If you know the answer why it didn't work with Windows, please explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AS i remember, when you put 1 dot infront of the line, you start at the directory you are. So then the line must look like this:

```
require("./../vendors/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
```

And that should work at windows and linux....

Comment: @Orbb The key here is `getcwd()`

Comment: @Orbb, as DaveRandom mentiod, can you use getcwd to got the current dir, and use that dir to go to somewhere else. You can make an dir path with dirname() http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: @Orbb, you can also get the current direcotry by using: `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @TWCrap In windows its ver 5.3.8 and in linux its 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17

Comment: @TWCrap yes dirname function is valid in both versions. But i cant figure out how to build path from getcwd using dirname. getcwd gives  "/var/www/project/cron/" in linux and "C:\" in windows. Not the common place, right?

Comment: Right, but if i remember right, can you use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the dir path of the file where it's called from. And i thenk that you can use that to get to the right dir, am i right???

Comment: No Problem ;-) I'm glad that i could help You Don't forget to mark the answer ;-)

Comment: @Orbb - '__DIR__ 'is another and a common way.

Comment: @phoenix - use __DIR__

Answer (score 2):

Do not use **absolute** paths if you really do not need so. It's safer and better to correctly set `include_path` so in case of move you just need to adjust one setting instead of digging thru whole project and all its files.

> So my doubt is, is there a difference in how parent directory notation work in widows and Linux?

Paths starting with `/` (i.e. `/foo/bar`) are absolute paths as starting `/` indicates root folder. On Windows you got drive letter there.

I also suggest using `require_once` to avoid duplicated requires (which is OK if you mix HTML with code, but "spaghetti code" is not recommended anyway), but may cause problems with code

Comment: `And these differences are not transparently handled by PHP` - yes, they are, in fact they are transparently handled by Windows itself. Windows (not just PHP) will allow you to use `/` as a path separator just about everywhere apart from cmd.exe. It will also treat a path beginning with `/` as starting from the route of the currently selected drive. If you write all the paths in your PHP scripts as if they were *nix paths, they will work on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I know "/" works on Windows, I was (not clearly) referring to lack root drive mapping. If I am wrong on that, then thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, at least on a UNIX system, when you start with a preceding slash on a file path you start at the root.

You should either write ./../*** or just ../ ond both systems. It should work both.